# processing.createAlgorithmDialog not filling default enum parameter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

not sure if this is the expected behavior of the `QgsProcessingParameterEnum`. I have a very very example Processing script. Not doing anything in the `processAlgorithm` method because I'm focused on the `initAlgorithm` one:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingParameterEnum,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       )

class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm2(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm2()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript2'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script2')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts 2')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Enum'),
                allowMultiple=True
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        pass
```

I have to create the algorithm dialog from another file (I'm creating a plugin) that should open the algorithm dialog and **fill** the enum parameter with the values of the dictionary:

```
dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
    'script:myscript2',
    {
       'INPUT': ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
)
dialog.exec_()
```

But the parameter list is empty. The reason is that I don't know in advance the values to pass to the enum parameters: `['a', 'b', 'c']` is just a silly example, in the real plugin the list with all the values is created by reading another file.

Is it possible to pass to the enum parameter a list with values not defined in the main algorithm file?

Answer (score 6):

I think the intended way is to define the options in the algorithm class

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Enum'),
                allowMultiple=True,
                options=['a', 'b', 'c']
            )
        )
```

Then you can pass the default parameter when using createAlgorithmDialog

```
dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
    'script:myscript2',
    {
       'INPUT': [0, 2]  # Select the 1st and 3rd option
    }
)
```

So you will have to find another way to modify your enum options. One quick and dirty solution using [QgsProcessingParameterEnum.setOptions](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsProcessingParameterEnum.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingParameterEnum.setOptions) that works in the console would be

```
from processing.gui.AlgorithmDialog import AlgorithmDialog

alg = QgsApplication.processingRegistry().createAlgorithmById('script:myscript2')
enum = alg.parameterDefinitions()[0]
enum.setOptions(['x', 'y', 'z'])
dlg = AlgorithmDialog(alg, parent=iface.mainWindow())
dlg.setParameters({'INPUT': [0, 2]})
dlg.exec_()
```